# How to delete all migration files in Django app

Tags: python, django, linux, find

I'm trying to delete all migration files in my Django app using a single command. Here's the structure of my repository:

```
|-- core
|   |-- migrations
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- 0001_initial.py
|       |-- 0002_add_column1.py
|       |-- 0003_add_column1.py
|
|-- users
    |-- migrations
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- 0001_initial.py
        |-- 0002_add_column2.py
```

My goal is to delete all files besides `__init__.py` so the repo looks like this:

```
|-- core
|   |-- migrations
|       |-- __init__.py
|
|-- users
    |-- migrations
        |-- __init__.py
```

I've tried the following command but no luck:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, but change 'ROOT' to your root folder name:

```
find . -path "./ROOT/*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

If running on Powershell use this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\src\*\migrations\*.py -Exclude __init__.py -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

Change src to your source folder